# «Не входить: частная собственность!» Как оформить текст?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания:

«Не входить: частная собственность!»

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от контекста. Если вы описываете знак (табличку), то следуйте оригиналу, скорее всего это передается двумя предложениями: «Не входить. Частная собственность» или «Не входить! Частная собственность!»

A если это прямая речь, то я бы предпочел тире: "Не входить - частная собственность!". В этом примере двоеточие плохо передает интонацию прямой речи.

Answer (score 1):

Речевой вариант нормально оформлен, пояснительная пауза, обозначенная двоеточием, вполне на месте:  **Не входить: частная собственность!**

А для таблички хорошо бы другой текст подобрать, например:  **Объект является частным владением, вход воспрещен!**